# Consolidate Pandas columns based on common value in the column header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of events and dates which, for the purposes of illustration, looks as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'yyyyww': ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03', '2022-01','2022-02','2022-03','2022-01','2022-03'],
                         '2001_52': [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         '2002_52': [0,30,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         '2003_52': [0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0],
                         '2001_23': [0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0],
                         '2002_23': [0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0],
                         'dis20': [0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0],
                         'dis30': [0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0],
                         'dis40': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,75],})
```

[image]

I want to parse each column header and combine the common columns into one, such that the output is as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'yyyyww': ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03', '2022-01','2022-02','2022-03','2022-01','2022-03'],
                         'wk_52': [10,30,50,0,0,0,0,0],
                         'wk_23': [0,0,0,20,15,0,0,0],
                         'dis': [0,0,0,0,0,25,15,75],})
```

[image]

My attempts have yielded the following which is evidently not quite the desired result as the first two columns are missing values, whereas the last column appears to be as expected.

```
# Create empty dict 
merge_data = {}

# loop through columns to parse name 
for col in df1.columns:
    if col.startswith('2') and '_' in col:
        key = col.split('_')[-1]
        if key.isdigit():
            if key not in merge_data:
                merge_data[key] = df1[col]
        else:
            merge_data[key] +=df1[col]

# merge columns and apply values to empty dict
merge_data_out = {f"wk_{key}": values for key, values in merge_data.items()}

# procedure for combining 'dis...' columns
merge_data_out['dis'] = df1.filter(like='dis').sum(axis=1)
merge_data_out = pd.DataFrame(merge_data_out)
merge_data_out
```

[image]

I would appreciate some guidance here as to how the desired result can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just take a sum across the relevant columns.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'yyyyww': ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03', '2022-01','2022-02','2022-03','2022-01','2022-03'],
                         '2001_52': [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         '2002_52': [0,30,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         '2003_52': [0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0],
                         '2001_23': [0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0],
                         '2002_23': [0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0],
                         'dis20': [0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0],
                         'dis30': [0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0],
                         'dis40': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,75],})

new_cols = {f'wk_{(wk:=col.split("_")[-1])}' if (x:='_' in col) else 'dis' : f'_{wk}' if x else 'dis' for col in df1.columns[1:]}
col_groups = {key: [col for col in df1.columns if pattern in col] for key, pattern in new_cols.items()}

for col in col_groups:
    df1[col] = df1[col_groups[col]].sum(axis = 1)

df2 = df1[new_cols.keys()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
idx = (df1.columns
          .str.replace(r'\d+_', 'wk_', regex=True)
          .str.replace(r'dis\d+', 'dis', regex=True)
      )

out = df1.groupby(idx, axis=1, sort=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
    yyyyww  wk_52  wk_23  dis
0  2022-01     10      0    0
1  2022-02     30      0    0
2  2022-03     50      0    0
3  2022-01      0     20    0
4  2022-02      0     15    0
5  2022-03      0      0   25
6  2022-01      0      0   15
7  2022-03      0      0   75
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename columns first then use some transformations to get the expected output:

```
# Rename columns with regex patterns
dmap = {r'dis\d+': 'dis', r'\d{4}_(\d+)': r'wk_\1'}
df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().replace(dmap, regex=True)

# melt: flat your dataframe
# query: remove irrelevant values
# assign: identify rows for each group of yyyyww
# pivot_table: reshape your dataframe
out = (df1.melt('yyyyww').query('value != 0')
          .assign(row=lambda x: x.groupby('yyyyww').cumcount())
          .pivot_table(index=['yyyyww', 'row'], columns='variable',
                       values='value', sort=False, fill_value=0)
          .sort_index(level='row').droplevel('row')
          .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    yyyyww  wk_52  wk_23  dis
0  2022-01     10      0    0
1  2022-02     30      0    0
2  2022-03     50      0    0
3  2022-01      0     20    0
4  2022-02      0     15    0
5  2022-03      0      0   25
6  2022-01      0      0   15
7  2022-03      0      0   75
```

Comment: for a relatively large dataset, the melt will be expensive, generally feels like a lot of work though

Answer (score 1):

An additional possible solution:

```py
merge_cols = ["_52", "_23", "dis"]

for m in merge_cols:
    cols = df1.columns
    subset = list(map(lambda x: m in x, cols))
    if "_" in m:
        m = f"wk{m}"
    df1[m] = df1.loc[:, subset].sum(axis=1)
    df1.drop(cols[subset], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

where `print(df1)` then gives:

```
    yyyyww  wk_52  wk_23  dis
0  2022-01     10      0    0
1  2022-02     30      0    0
2  2022-03     50      0    0
3  2022-01      0     20    0
4  2022-02      0     15    0
5  2022-03      0      0   25
6  2022-01      0      0   15
7  2022-03      0      0   75
```